# Regex to match html open and close tags(need some explanation)

Tags: regex

I have difficulties in understanding some nuances in regular expressions. I am following the tutorial http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html and stuck on the example of matching open and close tag using `backreferences`.

We have string:

```
Testing <B><I>bold italic</I></B> text
```

and expression:

```
<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>.*?</\1>
```

I can understand the whole logic, but can not get why engine backtracks to dot:

> The engine has now arrived at the second `<` in the regex, and the
>   second `<` in the string. These match. The next token is `/`. This does
>   not match `I`, and the engine is forced to backtrack to the dot. The dot
>   matches the second `<` in the string. The star is still lazy, so the
>   engine again takes note of the available backtracking position and
>   advances to `<` and `I`. These do not match, so the engine again
>   backtracks.

Why it backtracks to dot? Is this because we have successfully matched the previous part of regex and it always backtracks to the position of previous successful match + 1?

And the second part I can not get completely. If we have a string:

```
Testing <BOO><I>bold italic</I></B> text
```

and expression without word boundary:

```
<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)[^>]*>.*?</\1>
```

> ...and look inside the regex engine at the point where `\1` fails the
>   first time. First, `.*?` continues to expand until it has reached the
>   end of the string, and `</\1>` has failed to match each time `.*?` matched
>   one more character.
>
> Then the regex engine backtracks into the capturing group. `[A-Z0-9]*` has matched `oo`, but would just as happily match `o` or nothing at all. When backtracking, `[A-Z0-9]*` is forced to give up one character.

Why it backtracks into the capturing group and not to dot as in previous example? And I can not get why `[A-Z0-9]*` is forced to give up one character? Is there some general rule where engine will backtrack?

Comment: It backtracks because the matching was lazy (`.*?`)

Comment: @hjpotter92, I get that, but the question is why it backtracks to dot and not to `[^>]` for instance.

Comment: No, the lazy quantifier decides how far it matches, not when backtracking happens.  The backtracking occurs because `<I` does not match `</` just like it says in the narrative.

Comment: Backtracking is depth-first; the engine always backtracks as little as possible.  If backtracking fails to produce a match, it needs to backtrack more.  When there are no more opportunities to backtrack, the whole expression fails to match.

Comment: @tripleee, so am I correct suggesting that engine backtracks to last successful match?

Comment: It backtracks to `.` because it already has successfully found the `>` after `[^>]` set.

Comment: The page you link to explains that the lazy dot is a place which the engine takes note of in case it needs to backtrack later.  This is basically happening everywhere where an expression could match more than one way.

Comment: I doubt if the question can be answered. There are several smaller questions that are clearly described at regular-expressions.info. I think it should be closed unless there is a real problem. Maybe the only addition necessary is that  backtracking can go into the preceding capturing groups. The only place where backtracking has no access to are atomic groups and constructs with possessive quantifiers.

Comment: @stribizhev, I agree, there is no real problem. The problem is that I just can not understand why backtracking rolls back to particular position is general. In first case why it is dot and in second why it is jumps inside capturing group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***NOTE***: It is not about HTML parsing, it is a drill-down into how backtracking works using an HTML string example from http://regular-expression.info/backref.html.

> *The problem is that I just can not understand why backtracking rolls back to particular position is general.*

The point is that a regular expression engine tries to find a match by all means. If there are options, different paths it may follow based on the current pattern, it will try them once it finds unmatching symbols on its way. See this [backtracking introduction at rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html#intro):

> Backtracking is a wonderful feature of modern regex engines: **if a token fails to match, the engine backtracks to any position where it could have taken a different path**. A greedy quantifier may then give up one character, a lazy quantifier may expand to match one more, or the rightmost side of an alternation may be tried. **If a pattern continues to fail, the engine systematically explores all available paths.**

So, *backtracking may roll back to every construct or grouping that has a quantifier/alternation set to make sure all possible combinations are tried before a match failure is asserted*. Your assumption that it always backtracks to the last matched symbol is not correct.

The only places where backtracking does not have access to are atomic groups, or groups that have possessive quantifiers. Also, the fact that a *lookaround is zero-length automatically makes it atomic* (see [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)).

In the first regex, `\b` marks a word boundary, and thus there can be no backtracking into the capturing group as there is no other word boundary other than already matched. When you remove it, backtracking can test all the preceding locations inside the capturing group.

To understand the importance of backtracking and `\b`, compare these regexes against the `Testing <Boo><I>bold italic</I></Bo> text` input:

- [`<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)[^>]*>.*?<\/\1o>`](https://regex101.com/r/eE5mU6/1) - the match is found as no word boundary is set and the engine backtracks into the capturing group freely, and the capturing group may contain `B`, `Bo` and `Boo`.
- [`<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>.*?<\/\1o>`](https://regex101.com/r/eE5mU6/2) - no match is found as Group 1 can only contain `Boo`.